# How to make stem plot for convolution in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, convolution

I am new to Matlab.
I am learning convolution of function. So far I know, generally

> Convolution is multiplication of two function, or combining to signal to create a third signal.

Please amend me if I am wrong.

I am given two function which are `f(n)`and `g(n)`, in order to find the convolution of `f(n)*g(n)` , I did the coding like this:

```
n=-10:10;
w=conv(f,g,'same');
stem(n,w)
```

Is these the correct method? 
What should I do if I want to find convolution of `f(n)*f(n)*f(n)` ?

Comment: Technically it's not *just* the multiplication of two functions. But using `conv` is one way to do it. Study the `'same'` input to `conv` and make sure that `'valid'` or `'full'` aren't better options for you. Also you can chain the convolutions: `conv(conv(f, f, 'same'), f, 'same')`

Answer (score 0):

Convolution is multiplication of signal when signals are taken in frequency domain, not in time domain.
For 1-d convolution,

ch=conv(x,y);

stem(ch); works

For 2-d convolution,

ch=conv2(x,y)

use of stem3 would be better. But mesh can also be used.